# PHP MySqli how to get blob as 0x00000 string?

Tags: php, mysqli, attributes, blob

I have a table for things properties.
Such as id, amount, owner, attributes.
The attributes is stores as blob, and could be any small information about the thing itself,.
Like, the thing may have text on it, or it may has something about it that makes it more unique.

When you export a table/row in PhpMyAdmin, I get these really nice values

```
INSERT INTO `user_things` (`owner_id`, `id`, `thingId`, `count`, `attributes`) VALUES
(1, 6, 101, 1, 0x10c8431200);
```

And what I'm trying to do, is being able get information from the blob in PHP that displays the blob the same way PhpMyAdmin displayed it, so I can with PHP build a string of query there the blob value stays at a 0x00000 value.

**I've tried to use this code:** (mysqlQuery is a simplified function I created for mysqli queries, and that one works perfect so don't worry about that part)

```
$thing = mysqlQuery("SELECT * FROM `user_things` LIMIT 1;");
$blob = $thing["attributes"];
```

but it doesn't work very well, and I've tried `base64_encode` and that doesn't give me the 0x000 either.

I would highly appreciate any help on this, how I can get the blob to the same type of value that PhpMyAdmin displays it as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0x` is just a convention for expressing [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) values.

The `0x10c8431200` hexadecimal value is the same like `72079315456` decimal value.

You can try to convert binary data to hex with the `bin2hex` function.

Example:

```
$thing = mysqlQuery("SELECT * FROM `user_things` LIMIT 1;");
$blob = $thing["attributes"];
echo bin2hex($blog);
```

Comment: It works very well (with exception I have to add "0x" ti the string) but your post in general helped me out excellent in this matter!

Thank you very much for the help!